# Segmentation error in loop, Cant find error

Tags: c, while-loop

I have the following code that works perfectly fine, until in implement the while loop, it gives me a segmentation error, I cant find where it is.

```
#include <stdio.h>     /* for printf */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    char str[200];
    char *tok = NULL;
    char path[300];

    strcpy(str, "a/b/c/d");

    printf("string before strtok(): %s\n", str);
    #string before strtok(): a/b/c/d
    tok = strtok(str, "/");
    strcpy(path,tok);
    printf("Current Tok: %s\n", tok);
    #Current Tok: a
    strcat (path,"/");
    printf("Current Path:%s\n",path);
    #Current Tok: a/

    while (1){
    strcat(path, "/");
    tok = strtok(NULL, "/");
    strcat(path, tok);
    printf("Path after strcpy:%s\n",path);
        if (tok == NULL){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried doing it manually, doing each step, it works fine.

Comment: What line does your debugger say the error lies in?

Comment: I was using an online compiler, it simply said segmentation error, but if i remove the while loop, it works. So i was suspecting there is something wrong with the loop part, which I wasn't able to find.

Comment: For finding the line where the segmentation fault occurs. Compile the program like gcc -ggdb -o0 Filename.c -o Object_Name. Change the ulimit like $ulimit -c unlimited Then run the code $./Object_Name Now comes the final stage where you can find the line where the segmentation fault occurs. $gdb Object_Name core

Answer (score 6):

If you step through the code in a debugger, or look at the stack when it throws an exception,  you will see that the error is here:

```
 tok = strtok(NULL, "/");
```

the value of tok after this point is null.  You are then passing that null pointer value into

```
strcat(path, tok);
```

which causes the exception. I think you need to move your "if" condition to right after the tok assignment:

```
   tok = strtok(NULL, "/");
   if (tok == NULL)
        break;
```

If you are not familiar with using a debugger, then please spend some time learning how to.  It is your best friend.